How to handle accented characters with events KeyCode vb.net
I'm capturing the keyboard keys that are pressed by the CreateKeyboardHook event, where it returns all the keys that were pressed (making it a keylogger, without storing or anything like that, just printing to the console)
    Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim Kbd As New KeyboardStroke
            Dim hookTask As Task = Task.Run(Sub()
                                                Kbd.CreateKeyboardHook(Sub(keyPressed)
                                                                           Console.Write(keyPressed)
                                                                       End Sub)
                                                Application.Run()
                                            End Sub)
            hookTask.Wait()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

I "ran into" a problem (I don't know if it can be said to be a problem, as it is a function that listens to the keyboard keys) which is the issue of accentuation. I did several searches to try to combine accent + letter and didn't find anything related (any function specifically for this)
Would there be any way to deal with this? I thought of something related to recording the last key pressed and if that key is an accent, it waits for the next letter or key pressed, so if it is a vowel, it would combine the accent + the vowel (as vowels are the only letters that receive an accent , different from consonants..)
However, I was unable to apply or find any function that performs this "correction".
Of course this is something specific, like pt-BR keyboard layouts (for example)
The CreateKeyboardHook function follows:
Public Sub CreateKeyboardHook(ByVal keyPressedCallback As Action(Of KeyPressed))
        Me.keyPressedCallback = keyPressedCallback
        Me.HookKeyboardDelegate = AddressOf HookKeyboardCallbackImplementation
        Me.globalKeyboardHookId = User32.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Me.HookKeyboardDelegate, Me.currentModuleId, 0)
    End Sub

For a better understanding (avoid huge codes, but if necessary I will share them with you..)

the keyPressedCallback parameter is executed whenever the key is pressed (it is a way of defining what should happen when a keyboard event occurs)

the SetWindowsHookEx method is used to install a keyboard hook procedure, it receives some parameters such as the hook type (in this case WH_KEYBOARD_LL) a pointer to the function that will be called whenever a keyboard event occurs (the HookKeyboardDelegate), the handle of the current module, and a handle to the thread associated with the keyboard hook.

the HookKeyboardCallbackImplementation method is the function that will be called whenever a keyboard event occurs. It receives event information, such as the key code (nCode), the type of message (wParam) and a pointer to a structure that contains information about the key (lParam) here is where the actual processing of keyboard events happens


Below is a capture of the event:

